# How to change wi-fi country in Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: raspbian

My Raspberry Pi information:

```
> uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.19.93-v7l+ #1290 SMP Fri Jan 10 16:45:11 GMT 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux

> cat /etc/os-release                                                   
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

So I have set the wpa_supplicant like this:

```
> cat /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=US

network={
        ssid="<confidential>"
        psk="<confidential>"
}
```

I also have set this command:

> sudo iw reg set US

However, the output is

```
> sudo iw reg get
global
country 98: DFS-UNSET
        (2402 - 2472 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
        (5735 - 5815 @ 20), (N/A, 23), (N/A)
```

What is `98`? I expect the country will change to `US`. But not sure why `98` is showing up instead.

Also, after x (10-20) minutes, the country changed back to original value, which is `ID` (Indonesia) where I purchased my usb wireless dongle. I managed to create a simple script running with `systemd` that use `sudo iw reg set US`. However the country is still showing `98`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Do NOT fiddle with `iw`(or any other low level tool).

Run `sudo raspi-config` (or the GUI equivalent) and set appropriate `Localisation Options`

Comment: I’ve tried to do that as well, but got error saying `Could not communicate with wpa_supplicant`. Could it be because my usb wifi dongle has country region being set in the hardware level?

Comment: why should you not use IW?  What if the requirement is to automate the Wi-Fi country depending on User and where they live?  If  I want to provide a friendly interface what else could I use?